# Change colour of unselected Tab Bar Icon in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to change the colour of the unselected tab bar icon. They appear in grey!

I managed to change the text but dont know how to change the image colours to white!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052729/default-tab-bar-item-colors-using-swift-xcode-6 the selected answer on here should accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: Can you make an example and put it on drop box so I can access it and see how you did it please? @Bluehound